# Flutter Navigator operation requested with a context that does not include a Navigator. on splash screen

Tags: flutter, dart

so I'm trying to implement a splash screen where for two reasons.

1. the time given to the splash screen will be used to load all the data
2. For beautification

I'm using [flutter_spinkit](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_spinkit)
So here's my code:

```
class _SplashScreenState extends State<SplashScreen> {

  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    navigateToHomeScreen();
  }

  Future navigateToHomeScreen() async {
    return Timer(
      const Duration(milliseconds: 4000),
      () {
        Navigator.pushReplacement(context,
            MaterialPageRoute(builder: (BuildContext context) => App())); ---> doesn't go to new screen
      },
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: Scaffold(
        backgroundColor: Color(0xff75c760),
        body: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: [
            _buildAppName(),
            SizedBox(height: 20),
            _buildSpinner(),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget _buildAppName() {
    return Text(
      "MasterChef",
      style: GoogleFonts.robotoMono(
        color: Colors.black,
        fontStyle: FontStyle.normal,
        fontSize: 30,
        fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget _buildSpinner() {
    return SpinKitDoubleBounce(
      color: Colors.white,
    );
  }
}
```

and here's the `App()` from `app.dart`:

```
class _AppState extends State<App> {
  //Contains the simple drawer with switch case for navigation
  //Taken directly from the flutter docs
}
```

The basic idea is to load the splash screen for 4000 milliseconds in which the app will load all the necessary data and then navigate to App() which contains the navigation routes and all. But for some reason I'm getting `Unhandled Exception: Navigator operation requested with a context that does not include a Navigator.`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I cannot be certain to what the cause is as cannot see your entire app structure but I am guessing the cause is that you do not have a `MaterialApp()` at the root of your app.

If this doesn't work please update your question to contain more code of how you get the splash screen app to be displayed.

Comment: hey, that actually worked. Since I changed my `runApp(App())` to `runApp(SplashScreen())` there was no `MaterialApp()`. Thanks for the quick solve

Comment: No Problem, any time.

Answer (score 0):

This is because you used *return Timer()* so remove the **return** keyword so, try changing your code to:

```
Future navigateToHomeScreen() async {
  Timer(
   const Duration(milliseconds: 4000),
   () {
    Navigator.pushReplacement(context,
        MaterialPageRoute(builder: (BuildContext context) => App())); 
      },
     );
 }
```

Alternatively, you can use *Future* instead of *Timer*

```
Future navigateToHomeScreen() async {
  Future.delayed(
   const Duration(milliseconds: 4000),
   () {
    Navigator.pushReplacement(context,
        MaterialPageRoute(builder: (BuildContext context) => App())); 
      },
     );
 }
```

Comment: thanks but didn't work. still getting the navigator operation requested without a context that does not include a navigator

Comment: Believe you already got the answer, I didn't think you would miss MaterialApp.
No worries.